# R interpretation of STL() or decompose() results

Tags: r, time-series, decomposition

How can I interpret the results of the decomposition of a time series, especially from the seasonal results?

Example:

```
timeserie_beer = head(ausbeer, 12)
decompose(timeserie_beer)
```

Results:

```
$x
     Qtr1 Qtr2 Qtr3 Qtr4
1956  284  213  227  308
1957  262  228  236  320
1958  272  233  237  313

$seasonal
           Qtr1       Qtr2       Qtr3       Qtr4
1956   5.421875 -32.015625 -27.703125  54.296875
1957   5.421875 -32.015625 -27.703125  54.296875
1958   5.421875 -32.015625 -27.703125  54.296875
```

How can I calculate the 54,29 of the Qtr4?

The mean of all values is 261 and the means for the Qtrs:

- Qtr1 = 272
- Qtr2 = 224
- Qtr3 = 233
- Qtr4 = 313

In the plot of the base time series, I can see that the season is in Q4.

And is there a possibility to comprehend the seasonal values - how are they calculated?

Comment: Please do not [cross-post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45312442/interpretation-results-seasonal-decompose-and-stl).

Comment: I think my post is better here in stats. Should I delete the other post?

Comment: Yes. Also, if the link in your SO post is relevant, add it to your question here as well.

Comment: I change the post with an easy reproducable example, so the link isn't more relevant.